Why does the ENTER key release the wait?
The button executes the "resolve" function and releases the wait, as expected.
But then the ENTER key releases the wait also.  What's going on?
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Q:await </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
  "use strict";
  let fnresolve, n=0; // globals
window.onload = function() {
  zlog('Hit the button, then the ENTER key');
  zlog();
  Main();
}
async function Main() {
  do {
    zlog('before wait', ++n);    
    let pMain = new Promise((res) => { fnresolve = res; } ); // save the res function
    await pMain;
    zlog('after wait', n); zlog('');    
  } while (1);
}
function zlog() {
  document.getElementById('zlog').innerHTML += (Object.values(arguments).join(', ')) + '<br />';
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button onclick='fnresolve();'> fnresolve </button>
  <div id='zlog'></div>  
  </body>
</html>

EDIT: The answer and comments inspired the fix:
<button onclick='fnresolve();this.blur();'> fnresolve </button>


<button> element. In a typical HTML document, pressing the "ENTER" key can trigger the first button on the page as if it were clicked. Since your fnresolve function is associated with the button's onclick event, pressing "ENTER" triggers this event, causing the promise to be resolved.
Here is what you should update
<button type="button" onclick='fnresolve();'> fnresolve </button>



What took you so long?  7 minutes!  Thanks.

haha , apologies I had to visit the loo...

There's no form here however. It's probably just the button element having focus.

I tried to accept -- have to wait until after 15 minutes.

@Pointy spot on! you would always think about forms when you see buttons...

The "type" didn't help but this did:  fnresolve 

shall I update accordingly or you can edit the answer if you can @dcromley?
